# How to get opened/used files of a running process

Tags: c#, process

I try to figure out a way to get the used files of a process to show which files are currently opened / used by this process.

I have found *[Listing Used Files](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170)*.
Is there a link to get this in C#?

Comment: THe link you provided is cool, maybe try referencing it from your code? I mean create C++ libruary and create C# wrapper using DLL import.

Comment: I do not want to have extra dlls in my project..but good idea anyway! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function seems like a logical starting point, but you'd have to access it via [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services).

From my googling it seems like many people have thought of this approach in the past, but it has never been documented (at least not on [PInvoke.net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services#PInvoke.net)).

Comment: Thanks! Well, i have checked that...seems to be a long long way ;)